# How do I add a scroll to the dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll, scrollable

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in which I can scroll when the content doesn't fit on the screen. However, this isn't working as I want it to because there doesn't appear any scrollbar when the text goes off-screen.

How should I go about doing this?

This is my code:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.dropbtn {
  height: 28px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.Panel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Panel:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Panel:hover .dropbtn {
  background-size: 28px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 28px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Panel">
    <button class="dropbtn"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <br> <br>
      <a href="../" target="_self"> Home</a> <be>
      <a href="../" target="_self"> Other</a> <br>
      <a href="../" target="_self"> Other</a> <br>
      <a href="../" target="_self"> Other</a> <br>
      <a href="../" target="_self"> Other</a> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're gonna need to put that code in a code snippet not a google doc in order for it to be viewed.

Comment: I know doesn't let me. If someone can edit my post without throwing an error you're welcome ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. I've found the solution. It's basically that I need to give the size of the dropdown. Otherwise, CSS won't let me put a scroll.